# Return non reactive object from setup function

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I am using the new Nuxt3 composable *useAsyncData* to fetch a large csv file.
In the setup function I use the useAsyncData to pull the data ( d3.csv is a sort of fetch function)

```
const { data } = await useAsyncData(() =>
d3.csv(url)
)
```

Then I return the data from the setup function. I use it in the other methods of the component (which is written in the traditional Vue options API).

When I observe the data object in the chrome dev tools, it is a ref or a reactive proxy. The thing is that I don't want to have such a large reactive object, because it is not going to change.

How can I return the raw object instead of the reactive version? Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: useAsyncData is supposed to be reactive due to the way it works. You probably don't need it at all, like `data = await d3.csv()`, but this is specific to Nuxt.

Comment: The thing is that I need to place the code within useAsyncData because at the end I want that data to be available at when SSR processing happens.

Comment: Probably looking for that one: https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-advanced.html#toraw

Comment: For the data that have to be fetched on the server, you can use the `onServerPrefetch` hook. It is the Vue's standard hook but I'm not sure if it works with Nuxt